# Why does this custom function cost too much time while backward in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm revising a baseline method in pytorch. But when I add a custom function in the training phase, the cost time of backward increases 4x on a single V100. Here is an example of the custom function:

```
def batch_function(M, kernel_size=21, sf=2):
    '''
    Input:
        M: b x (h*w) x 2 x 2 torch tensor 
        sf: scale factor
    Output:
        kernel: b x (h*w) x k x k  torch tensor
    '''

    M_t = M.permute(0,1,3,2)  # b x (h*w) x 2 x 2
    INV_SIGMA = torch.matmul(M_t, M).unsqueeze(2).unsqueeze(2)  # b x (h*w) x 1 x 1 x 2 x 2

    X, Y = torch.meshgrid(torch.arange(kernel_size), torch.arange(kernel_size))
    Z = torch.stack((Y, X), dim=2).unsqueeze(3).to(M.device)   # k x k x 2 x 1

    Z = Z.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0) # 1 x 1 x k x k x 2 x 1
    Z_t = Z.permute(0,1,2,3,5,4)  # 1 x 1 x k x k x 1 x 2
    raw_kernel = torch.exp(-0.5 * torch.squeeze(Z_t.matmul(INV_SIGMA).matmul(Z)))  # b x (h*w) x k x k 

    # Normalize
    kernel = raw_kernel / torch.sum(raw_kernel, dim=(2,3)).unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1)   # b x (h*w) x k x k 

    return kernel
```

where b is the batch size, 16; h and w are the spatial dimensions, 100; k is equal to 21. I'm not sure if the large dimension of M causes the cost time longer.
Why does the cost time longer? And are there other methods to rewrite this code to improve it?
I'm new here, so if the problem is not clearly described, please let me know!

Comment: Your operation involves tensors which are quite huge.

Comment: May be. I have rewriting the last two lines of code, to use softmax fucntion in pytorch, while the time cost is still expensive.

Comment: Did you profile your code to see which operation was the bottleneck?

Comment: I just tested. The estimation of raw_kernel cost the most time, mainly in the two operations 'matmul'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to get a performance boost on the double tensor multiplication by using `torch.einsum`:

```
>>> o = torch.einsum('acdefg,bshigj,kldejm->bsdefm', ZZ_t, INV_SIGMA, ZZ)
```

The resulting tensor `o` will be shaped `(b, h*w, k, k, 1, 1)`

---

For details on the subscript notation:

- `b`: batch dimension.
- `s`: 's' for **s**patial, *i.e.* the `h*w` dimension.
- `d` and `e`: the two *k* dimensions which are paired across `ZZ_t` and `ZZ`.

A simple 2D matrix multiplication applying matmul with `ij,jk->ik`.

Keeping that in mind, we have in your case:

- A first multiplication: `r = ZZ_t@INV_SIGMA` 
  which does something like `*fg,*gj->*fj`, 
  *the asterisk sign `*` refers to leading dimensions*.
- A second matrix multiplication: `r@INV_SIGMA` 
  which comes down to `*fj,*jm->*fm`.

Overall, if we combine both, we get directly: `*fg,*gj,*jm->*fm`.

Finally, I have assigned all other dimensions to random *but different* subscript letters:

```
a, c, f, h, i, k, l
```

Replacing the asterisk above with those notations, we get the following subscript input:

```
#  *  fg, *  gj, *  jm-> *  fm
# acdefg,bshigj,kldejm->bsdefm
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The using of torch.einsum speeds almost 10x of my code! I will make full use of it in the future. I'm new here, so there is little reputation to cast a vote. But I am so grateful for that! My final code will be released later for reference by others.

Answer (score 1):

Thank Ivan! As Ivan suggests, I rewrite the code as follows for reference by others.

```
def batch_function(M, kernel_size=21, sf=2):
    '''
    Input:
        M: b x (h*w) x 2 x 2 torch tensor
        sf: scale factor
    Output:
        kernel: b x (h*w) x k x k  torch tensor
    '''

    INV_SIGMA = torch.matmul(torch.einsum('...ij->...ji', M), M).unsqueeze(2)  # b x (h*w) x 1 x 2 x 2

    X, Y = torch.meshgrid(torch.arange(kernel_size), torch.arange(kernel_size))
    Z = torch.stack((Y, X), dim=2).to(M.device).view(1,1,-1,2,1)   # 1 x 1 x k^2 x 2 x 1

    logits = -0.5 * torch.einsum('acdfg,bshgj,kldjm->bsdfm', torch.einsum('...ij->...ji', Z), INV_SIGMA, Z)  # b x (h*w) x k x k 

    kernel = F.softmax(logits, dim=2).view(M.size(0), M.size(1), kernel_size, kernel_size)  # b x (h*w) x k x k 

    return kernel
```

There are three main ways to shorten the running time:

- `torch.einsum` improves the double tensor multiplication.  :) mainly
- `torch.nn.functional.softmax` integrates the last two lines of code.
- Reducing the creation of intermediate variables.